# Yosemite won't empty trash

Tags: macos, trash

Re: [Yosemite does not like emptying the trash](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/yosemite-does-not-like-emptying-the-trash)

So I'm not tech savvy but am having this very same problem with the trash after upgrading to Yosemite. I typed `lsof +D ~/.Trash` and this is what I got

```
COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
UserEvent 699 romaabraham 11r DIR 1,2 68 35694329 /Users/romaabraham/.Trash
```

I am not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

I infrequently have an issue where something is locking whatever item is in the Trash.  I reboot, and 10 times out of 10, I'm able to empty it.

For example, I save a screenshot to my desktop, then send it as a Mail.app attachment.  Once the mail is sent, I try to Trash and empty the screenshot.  I am unabvle to do so until I quit Mail and empty Trash.